# How to set Update_column to Object level in hasura Upsert mutation

Tags: upsert, hasura

how we can set seperate update_columns list for each object inside the array object while using on_conflct upsert?

eg: i have a table called User and it have fields like id,name and age

Requirement:
in the upsert action i need to upsert a list of user.. like user1(need to update age field only), user2(need to update name), user3(need to update age and name). currently update_columns is common. so how we can set update_columns to object level?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `update_columns` as a variable to your mutation. If you check the docs in the GraphiQL tab, under `mutation_root` you can see the types that Hasura autogenerates.  I believe the type for the `update_columns` for the table `user` will be something like `user_update_column`

You mutation, having the `update_columns` as a variable will look something like this:

```
mutation ($update_columns:  [user_update_column!]!) {
  insert_users(
    objects: {id: "1", name: "name", email: "joe@gmail.com", age: 30},
    on_conflict: { 
      constraint: users_pkey, 
      update_columns: $update_columns
    }
  ){
    id
    name
    email
  }
}
```

And pass the columns that you need to update as the variable.

Comment: update_columns property just for setting what are the columns need to update during the mutation call. here if i set update_columns = [name], then after the mutation call only the name field of that particular record will update